# Why am I receiving an observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context: message with a null observed object?

Tags: ios, objective-c, key-value-observing

I have an object that is receiving an `observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:` message which it is not handling. This seems to be because I decide whether to handle it or not based on the class of the observed object, and in this case the observed object being passed is `null`!
Obviously I could just bin such messages concerning `null` objects, but why am I receiving such a message?
It does seem to concern an object that I was observing, because I recognise the `keypath` with the message. I will therefore be looking through to make sure I removed all observers that were added, but I will still like to know how a `null` observed object can be sending a message!

Comment: can you paste some code where you think this error is being thrown? (based on the backtrace)

Comment: my guess is that it has been release after sending the observer or you might have a thread issue over there, not really sure need to se the code.

Comment: It's being thrown in the `observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:` method, because I call super so that I can see any observed objects that are not expected (a log in that method shows that the observed object is null). I suppose threading could be a contender - it is a CoreData object, which I think is updated on another thread before merging the context onto the main thread.